# In Pandas, how can a DataFrame be binned by two columns, with the other columns changed to the means within those bins?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cut, resampling

I've got the standard iris dataset projected down to two dimensions using UMAP, with the UMAP dimensions for the x and y positions of the 2D plot added as columns to the dataframe:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import umap # pip install umap-learn

iris = load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
iris_df['species'] = pd.Series(iris.target).map(dict(zip(range(3), iris.target_names)))

_umap = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(iris.data)
iris_df['UMAP_x'] = _umap[:,0]
iris_df['UMAP_y'] = _umap[:,1]
iris_df.head()
```

I'd like to bin both the `UMAP_x` and `UMAP_y` columns into like 25 bins and then the other columns in the dataframe change to being the mean values of the columns in each of the bins. How might this be done? It feels like `cut` or resampling might lead to the answer, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` to define bins and then use `groupby` with `transform` to calculate mean value for each bin.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import umap

iris = load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
iris_df['species'] = pd.Series(iris.target).map(dict(zip(range(3), iris.target_names)))

_umap = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(iris.data)
iris_df['UMAP_x'] = _umap[:,0]
iris_df['UMAP_y'] = _umap[:,1]

# Define bins for UMAP_x and UMAP_y params
iris_df['UMAP_x_bin'] = pd.cut(iris_df['UMAP_x'], bins=25)
iris_df['UMAP_y_bin'] = pd.cut(iris_df['UMAP_y'], bins=25)

# Calculate mean value for each bin
iris_df['UMAP_x_mean'] = iris_df.groupby('UMAP_x_bin')['UMAP_x'].transform('mean')
iris_df['UMAP_y_mean'] = iris_df.groupby('UMAP_y_bin')['UMAP_y'].transform('mean')

iris_df.head()
```

Comment: Ah, magic, thanks for that! I was actually thinking of getting the individual means of the other features -- sepal length and so on -- within the resulting bin 'grid cells', but your approach works fine for that purpose also.